# Fetching variable value through ssh from destination to source server

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, redhat

This is my first question on StackOverFlow. I'm trying to write a shell script on a source server from where I need to connect to another server to get some value and store it in a variable. Then I need to disconnect from the destination server and use that variable in rest of the script. The below logic which I'm trying to use doesn't yields any result.

```
ssh <Destination server IP>
status=sudo systemctl status httpd | grep active
```

Now I'm expecting status variable should contain the status of the httpd service of the destination server which I can use in current source server script, but the value is blank. 
Also it must disconnect from the destination server. Not sure how to proceed with this.

Can someone please assist in this ? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you need bash

Comment: I'm using shell script as .sh , what else do you mean? Could you please elaborate your solution? 
-Thanks

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can execute from the client server:

ssh user@destination-server-ip 'bash -s' < your-command.sh > your-script.sh

when your-command is like:

```
status=sudo systemctl status httpd | grep active
echo status
```

and your your-script.sh must read status from standard input.

In example, maybe exists better solutions.

Comment: I'm sorry my answer is not complete for your question. You need to get the status....mmm, i think you can echo the status and redirect to a file or to another script...

Comment: Redirecting through a file and fetching output is possible but its not an option in our environment because unfortunately our client doesn't allows that, hence I was looking for a solution in which we could fetch value of the variable.Do we have any such alternative?